# How to use compute function in Metal API in iOS for Multiplication

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, metalkit, metal-performance-shaders

I am new to Metal API in iOS. So my question is, how to use Metal compute function for Multiplication, for instance,

let say we are having two float[] arrays of length 2048, we want to multiplicate corresponding elements together forming another array of floats[] of 2048

like this

res[i] = a[i] * b[i];

With a[] and b[] an array of 2048 floats

and res[] another array of 2048 floats

The next step is to perform that "operation", 2048 times.

Can someone please help me with this.

if possible, I need to do this in Objective-c, but I can read swift as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use accelerate in cpu? CPU is faster for long array.

Comment: You can use MetalPerformanceShader to do this.

Comment: @E.Coms Thanks, MetalPerformanceShader was just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial : https://machinethink.net/blog/mps-matrix-multiplication/
As well as This one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSofOJrFsJ4&ut=

Really helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

You should start with a working example and then adapt it to fit your needs. Here is a [prefix sum implementation](https://github.com/mdejong/MetalPrefixSum) that runs on top of Metal. This is a render implementation as opposed to a compute shader so that it is able to run effectively on the A7 chip.